# keyboard shift key is working without pressing the key

Tags: keyboard

I have acer aspire one laptop, since I have changed my operating system from windows 7 to windows 8.1, my laptop keyboard and touchpad is not working properly.
For number keys I switched on caps lock key, even this is not working, only uppercase be change into lowercase.

Comment: "changed my operating system from windows 7 to windows 8.1" How was this done specifically?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing some drivers.

Please go to the Acer download webpage of
[Drivers and Manuals](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers),
enter your device serial number, SNID or model number, then choose
Windows 8.1 (64- or 32-bit).

You should pay attention especially to the BIOS/Firmware latest version
and check it against yours (to avoid an unnecessary dangerous installation),
the Chipset Driver, and the Touchpad Driver (verify Synaptics or ELANTECH).

If this does not help, please tell us more how you installed Windows 8.1
and what version.

Comment: Function keys are not working in bios setup.......how can I update my operating system?

Comment: You do this from Windows, no reason to go into the BIOS. Don't touch the BIOS if you don't FULLY understand it.